# Xero Accounting Sdk Core: authentication error

Tags: c#, azure-functions, xero-api

I'm implementing an internal procedure to generate invoices from my database. In using `.NET Core`. I installed the Xero.Api.SDK.Core v. 1.1.4

I find the Xero documentation quite difficult to understand and a bit up to date. I took a look to the [Github](https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Net) repository and they refer only to `OAuth 2.0`. In my case I don't want any user interaction because I want a background process.

I created an account as developer and a demo company for test.

[image]

I googled a bit and I found in a site an example how to connect to the api (I couldn't find any details in the Xero documentation).

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"public_privatekey.pfx", "password");

var api = new Xero.Api.Example.Applications.Private.PrivateAuthenticator(cert);

var private_app_api = new XeroCoreApi("https://api.xero.com", 
                                      new PrivateAuthenticator(cert),
                                      new Consumer("ClientId", "ClientSecret"), 
                                      null, null);
```

Now, I thought, I should use the api. I tried to read the list of contacts:

```
var contacts = private_app_api.Contacts;
var list = contacts.FindAsync().Result;
```

The result is the following error:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown&oauth_problem_advice=Consumer%20key%20was%20not%20recognised)'
>
> Inner Exception
>   UnauthorizedException: oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown&oauth_problem_advice=Consumer%20key%20was%20not%20recognised

Then, I downloaded the repository from Github. I copy and paste the ClientId and ClientSecret and run the tests. No one test is passed!

[image]

My goal is to create a contact or find one in the list, create an invoice and save the invoice in PDF format in my storage.

How can I do that? Is there any example for that?

PS: In the [developer forum](https://community.xero.com/developer) the login doesn't work and the Postman collection is old and it doesn't either.

### Update

I was desperate. I tried to connect to the apis in another way with `XOauth`. Worst. I created the connection as Xero explains on [Github](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xoauth).

[image]

When I try to connect with

> xoauth connect

a new tab in my browser is opened and...

[image]

### Postman Update

I followed the steps with [Postman](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/tools/postman). I opened the collection in my Postman. In the environment I updated client_id and client_secret from the Xero Developer site and then the following configurations:

> re_directURI: https://developer.xero.com
>
> scopes: offline_access profile email accounting.transactions
>
> Auth URL: https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize
>
> Access Token: https://identity.xero.com/connect/token

I opened **Get started** api, **Generate token** and I gave the same result.

[image]

Comment: Look on the youtube channel. There's a video showing how to do a machine-to-machine connection which you'll need for a background process. I'm doing a Windows service, which is also background. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7DA_vntKKChsenzpL7QWPg/videos

Comment: Your code is using the old-style OAuth 1 calls, and while you can still create apps that way using a special link, you'll only be able to do that until June. So there's not a lot of point in creating new stuff using that now.

Comment: This is in the documentation and in the Github repository. I found everything very confused and messy. I tried to look the Youtube channel, it is worse: most of the video are old. There is only one video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcf_64yreVI quite chaotic and I can't understand how to do that.

Comment: Oh, that's the one I was thinking of, that cleared up a few things for me. I don't use the API now, I use XOAuth to get the token in the first place, then a HTTP POST to refresh it when needed, and HTTP get or post as required to interact with Xero. My problem with the sample code is I'm using VB, not c#, so I either had to try to translate from an unfamiliar language, or learn one.

Comment: With `XOAuth` you created the first token and with this one you call the other api. Is it working? If the token expired, what are you doing?

Comment: I create an access token and a refresh token with XOauth. The refresh token has an expiry, and my code checks that before accessing Xero. If it's expired, I call the refresh endpoint (as described in that video) and get a new pair of tokens, and a new expiry. I don't use the API now - I couldn't see how to refresh from the API, so once I'd got HTTP get and post working, there didn't seem any point adding complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it was quite a mess. I spent more than 2 weeks to understand how to call Xero. I created a [post to explain step by step](https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/csharp/integrate-xero-with-csharp-applications/) what I have to do.

There were a lot of issues:

- understand the Xero documentation because it is not very clear
- find the right values to put in the request
- translate the Postman request in code
- no Xero documentation for that, only a useless bunch of projects

It is quite long to explain everything but for example if you want to read an Organization the code with `RestSharp` is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the organizations.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>OrganizationResponse.</returns>
public OrganizationResponse GetOrganizations()
{
    var _client = new RestClient("https://api.xero.com/connections");
    _client.Timeout = -1;

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _settings.AccessToken);
    var response = _client.Execute<IList<Organization>>(request);

    return response;
}
```

I'll create other posts to explain how to implement more functions.

I created a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PSC.Accounting.XeroConnector/) package for that. Source code on [Github](https://github.com/erossini/XeroConnector).